# VS warning: Disposable object created by 'disposable' is never disposed, why?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, idisposable

I am writing a C# application and have stumbled across something that makes me unsure if it is a Visual Studio bug, or my knowledge is incorrect.

The culprit is a using statement inside "catch" part of a try/catch, where Visual Studio 2019 shows a warning that a disposable object will not be disposed:

> Disposable object created by 'MakeMeSomeDisposableObject()'s is never
>   disposed

The same statement used outside the catch, shows no warning message.

Here is an example of what I am talking about:

```
try
{
    SomeMethodThrowingExceptions();
}
catch
{
    using(var someDisposableObject = MakeMeSomeDisposableObjects())
    {
        someDisposableObject.SaveTheWorldFromException();
    }
}
```

My understanding is that in case of an exception - the disposable object will save the world and get disposed of after finishing its job because of the using statement. Visual Studio however thinks otherwise and shows a warning message, but also shows no fix - is this a VS bug or am I wrong about how using statements work in a catch?

Comment: "Disposable object created by 'MakeMeSomeDisposableObject()'s is never disposed". It's the warning hint when you press ctrl + .

Comment: @TimSchmelter The part about using inside the catch is relevant though - other usages of this method with a "using" statement don't show this warning, which makes me unsure if it's not just an IDE bug.

Comment: and just to be sure, if you put the `using` block inside the try, or outside of the try catch all together, then the error message goes away?

Comment: @CaseyCrookston Exactly.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio?

Comment: VS 2019 Professional, 16.2.4

Comment: I also don't get it in VS 2017 (15.9.9).

Comment: Code analysis warnings about IDisposable usage are notoriously unreliable, it does skirt having to solve the halting problem.  There is no history of getting this specific usage wrong, maybe it doesn't actually look like that?  Anyhoo, just move on, [disable the warning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/use-roslyn-analyzers?view=vs-2019#suppress-violations) and let Microsoft know about it with Help > Send Feedback > Report a Problem.

Comment: Checked the exact code on a borrowed machine from a colleague - nothing shows up on older VS version. I will just report it to Microsoft and call it a day.

Comment: Maybe its because the compiler expands a using block into an actual `try/catch` block; its hiding `MakeMeSomeDisposableObject` now. What happens if you declare `someDisposableObject` outside and then add a `finally` block and dispose of it there?

Comment: What I am trying to explain is that the `catch` block can actually throw an error *if* that using statement could fail, so the compiler is telling you its possible that `MakeMeSomeDisposableObjects` doesn't get disposed inside that catch because the using statement creates it's own try/catch and hence it's only a warning... TBH you shouldn't do this, do it inside the try and or declare it outside...

Comment: Can you try this `using var someDisposableObject = MakeMeSomeDisposableObjects; someDisposableObject.SaveTheWorldFromException();` does it still give you the warning?

Comment: I will, but it's the "Friday afternoon when things are burning and it's a release day" time of the year, so it will land on a to-do list.